# unable to load rJava package in R

Tags: java, r, windows, rjava

I went through many post about this but did not find the solution. I am using R 4.0.0 on a 64bit windows computer. I am trying yo install rJava, but it does not work.

The error message is :

```
> library(rJava)


Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/myself/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.
```

I am using a 64bits computer. I checked the compatibility between R/java.

I have installed both java "jdk" (jdk-14.0.1) and "jre" (jre1.8.0_251). I double checked that I am actually using the 64bit version. I also tried to keep only one of the two versions, but it did not work...

I did not specified any JAVA_HOME path, as it seems to be required in the latest version of rJava (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/NEWS).

Comment: I have same problem. I did specify the JAVA_HOME, but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

After going through the exact same problem and a lot of testing out JAVA_PATH to no avail I managed to solve it by doing the following:

- Uninstall JDK
- Uninstall Java
- Uninstall R
- Install R
- Install Java (Offline 64 bit https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)
- Install JDK (Version 8 64 bit https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)
- install rJava package through rStudio ( install.packages("rJava") )
- loaded rJava

The PATH variable in my system variables includes "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\bin" and it now works